# Confusing limits question

Tags: limits

Suppose that a and b are real numbers. Consider the function f: X -> Y (where X ⊆ R and Y ⊆ R), given by,

f(x) =

1/(x-1) + b for x < π, where defined

a for x = π

tan ((x^2)/π) for x > π, where defined.

a) Find lim x->π- (f(x)):

Just plug π into the equation for x < π, giving
1/(π - 1) + b

b) Find lim x->π+ (f(x)):
This just requires plugging x = π into the equation given in f(x) for x > π, i.e:
tan ((π^2)/π) = tan (π) = 0

c) For what values of a and b does lim x-> π (f(x)) exist?
d) For what values of a and b is f continuous at π?
e) Determine all real numbers that are not in the domain of f:

This three parts of the question have confused me. Firstly, I struggle to understand the difference in question between c and d. I think one of the answers should be a - b = 1/(pi - 1)? But I'm unsure which one. I think this is correct, but I am unsure because not all three parts would be valid, but it would make f(x) continuous from x <= π. My thoughts on the other part may be, if you plug in x = π into the 3 sections, then you get 0 for the third region, does this mean you have to make the other sections = 0? In which case, would a = 0 and b = - 1/(pi - 1)? Am I on the right lines?

Finally for e I believe the answer may just be x = 1, but since tan is invalid for ((2k -1)/π) where k is an element of N, would that mean. You would need, say, x^2/π = π/2, in which case x = π/root(2), and you can do the same for the other values, but is this even valid? As π/root (2) < π which is not in the given range for that section. So would it only apply for 3π/2, 5π/2,...? And so would the correct answer be 1, root((2k + 1)/2)π for k is a natural number?

Answer (score 1):

Answer for c): $b=\frac 1 {1-\pi}$.
For d): $a=0$ and $b=\frac 1 {1-\pi}$.
For e): $f$ is defined for all $x$ except $x=1$ and $x =\sqrt {n+\frac 1 2} \pi$, $n=1,2,...$.

Comment: Why is that the answer for c?, and what is the value for a?

Comment: For the limit to exist the value of the function at $\pi$ does not matter. You just want the right hand limit to be equal to the left hand limit, so you want $\frac 1 {\pi -1}+b=0$. But for d) you want the limit to be equal to the value $f(\pi)$. @SamConnell